# How to allow specific requests when using spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've a scenario where I need to let some request (let's say request method is GET) so that no 401 error can be thrown.

Below is my Spring Security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**")
                .antMatchers("/images/**")
                .antMatchers("/scripts/**")
                .antMatchers("/styles/**")
                .antMatchers("/views/**")
                .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**")
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/register")
                .antMatchers("/app/rest/activate");
    }
}
```

And this is my `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` implementation:

How can I allow requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method called `requestMatchers` where you can call it with one or more [`RequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/RequestMatcher.html) implementaions.

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http){
    .....

    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new MethodTypeRequestMatcher(RequestMethod.GET));

   .....

}
```

And you can define your implementation:

```
public class MethodRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
    private RequestMethod method;

    public MethodRequestMatcher(RequestMethod method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (method == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return request.getMethod().equals(method.name());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I think you can try like follows:

<code>
    @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.headers()
                    .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                    .xssProtection()
                    .frameOptions()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                    // PERMIT ALL
                    .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()               
                    // UNAUTHENTICATED USER
                    .antMatchers("/ForgetPassword").anonymous()
                     // TO SPECIFIC PERSON              
                    .antMatchers("/Report").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('S_USER')");
    }
</code>
```